# kafka-node: send enum key message (instead of string key)

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

I'm using [kafka-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kafka-node)  to produce messages from my node.js web-server. My consumer is another back-end system (written in c++ with [librdkafka](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka)).

I wonder how can I send keyed message (with kafka-node) where the key is int (enum) and not string..

**node.js code (producer):**

```
var kafka = require('kafka-node'),
        Producer = kafka.Producer,
        KeyedMessage = kafka.KeyedMessage,
        client = new kafka.Client(),
        producer = new Producer(client),
        km = new KeyedMessage(1, (new MessageTypeSystemStatus({trace: [{ }] })).encode()),
        payloads = [
            { topic: 'Genesis', messages: km, partition: 0 }
        ];
```

**C++ code (consumer):**

```
Message* msg = mConsumer->consume(mTopic, mPartition, -1);
*(msg->key_pointer());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to keep it update, if it may help someone..
I consulted with both libraries developers groups:
C++: librdkafka supports all types of keys (int/enum as well) - you can see this [issue](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/issues/640).

JavaScript: kafka-node still not support it, but it's in their roadmap for 1.0.0 as you can see from this [issue](https://github.com/SOHU-Co/kafka-node/issues/361).

Currently, I'm working with a string key due to this limitation of kafka-node - hope they will support other key types in the future as well.

Thanks all!